# How does AR.js uses its' tracking backend?

Tags: javascript, android, augmented-reality, arcore, ar.js

I want to extend [AR.js](https://medium.com/arjs/announcing-tango-support-for-ar-js-373572fec69e) by adding my own tracking backend. However, I have troubles finding any documentation on the architecture of this library or how it interacts with underlying components. Likewise, it'd be useful to have more information on how AR.js relates to ARToolkit, Tango, A-Frame, WebVR, ARCore and [WebARonARCore](https://github.com/google-ar/WebARonARCore). Since the area is quite new and striving, there are a lot of projects going on simultaneously and it's quite confusing and hard to differentiate their functionality sometimes.

The backend I need to implement is the object recognition based on [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/). I have a prototype running - Android Unity Tango application, it offloads video captured from the device camera onto the edge node, where it is processed in real-time and the information about recognized objects is sent back to the device, where it is used to render annotations. I'd like to have these annotations to be represented as [a-frame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/introduction/entity-component-system.html) tags, in order to make content layering easy by using JavaScript.

Any ideas/pointers are welcomed.